# Problem with showing that operations of defined set are $n$-transitive

Tags: linear-transformations

I have two problems which I have been thinking about since several days. They are connected with transitive operations.

1. We are considering the group $G$ of all linear transformations of real line in a form $x\rightarrow ax+b$, where $a\in\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$. Is the natural operation $G$ on $\mathbb{R}$ strictly $2$-transitive?
2. Let's assume that the group $G$ acts $1$-transitively on the set $S$. What's more, let's assume that for certain $x \in S$ the stabilizer $\operatorname{Stab}_{G(x)}$ acts strictly $2$-transitive on $S\backslash \{x\}$. How to prove that $G$ acts strictly $3$-transitive on $S$?

I would apprectiate any help, because I don't have any ideas. Below I have written a definition of $n$-transitive operation.

---

**Definition (*$n$-transitive operation*)** *Operation of group $G$ on the set $S$ is [strictly] $n$-transitive if for every sequences $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ and $(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)$ which each of them are composited from different in pairs elements of the set $S$, exists [exactly one] element $g \in G$, s. t. for every $i\leq n$ is reached $gx_i=y_i$.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.

   Given $x_1,x_2, y_1,y_2\in\mathbb{R}$ as in your definition, the points $(x_1,y_1),\,(x_2,y_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ uniquely determine a straight line containing both of them. This line is neither horizontal (since $y_1\ne y_2$) nor vertical (since $x_1\ne x_2$), and thus of the form $y=ax+b$ with $a\ne0$. In other words, there is a unique element in $G$ that sends $x_1$ to $y_1$ and $x_2$ to $y_2$.
2. I assume that you mean that *for any* $x\in S$, the stabiliser of $x$ acts strictly *1-transitively* on $S\!\setminus\!\{x\}$.

   Take $x_1,x_2, y_1,y_2\in S$ as in the definition. Then there exists an element $g\in G$ such that $g\cdot x_1=y_1$. Let $h\in G$ be the (unique) element in the stabiliser of $y_1$ that sends $g\cdot x_2$ to $y_2$. Then $hg\cdot x_1 = y_1$ and $hg\cdot x_2 = y_2$, which proves that $G$ acts 2-transitively on $S$.

   For strictness, assume that $g,h\in G$ both are elements that send $x_1$ to $y_1$ and $x_2$ to $y_2$. You need to show that $g=h$. To do this, compare the actions of the two group elements $g^{-1}h$ and $1_G$ on $S\!\setminus\!\{x_1\}$. Fill in the details yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand your reasoning to the moment _which proves that $G$ acts 2-transitively on $S$._ Could you explain more to me how to show 3-transitivity, because I don't see it at all?

Comment: @Novice: What do you mean? There is nothing about 3-transitivity in the question, nor in my answer.

The second statement in the question, as you wrote it, is not true. I made a guess of what you meant to say, but if I were mistaken then please clarify.

Comment: I am very sorry. There was a typo in my post... I have done an edit. I had in mind to prove, that the group $G$ acts strictly $3$-transitively. I am very sorry once more. Now everything is in proper place in my post.

Comment: Well, you can use the same idea to prove that. Or, more generally, the following: if $G$ acts transitively on $S$ and, for any $x\in S$, the stabiliser of $x$ acts strictly $(n-1)$-transitively on $S\setminus\{x\}$, then $G$ acts strictly $n$-transitively on $S$.